# Instance of a custom class assigned to Kivy ObjectProperty doesn't update GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties, kivy

I am trying to use Kivy Properties to refresh GUI after property is changed. However, when I try to assign an instance of custom class to property it doesn't work. After modifying property GUI is not refreshed with new value.

MWE:

python file:

```
from typing import List
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class SomeStruct:
    def __init__(self, atr1: List[int], atr2: str):
        self.atr1 = atr1
        self.atr2 = atr2


class Root(Screen):
    prop1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    prop2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.prop1 = SomeStruct(atr1=[1, 2, 3], atr2="test1")
        self.prop2 = "control1"

    def modify1(self):
        self.prop1.atr1 = [3, 2, 1]

    def modify2(self):
        self.prop1.atr2 = "test2"

    def modify3(self):
        self.prop2 = "control2"


class Mwe(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mwe().run()
```

kv file:

```
Root:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: str(root.prop1.atr1)
            on_press: root.modify1()
        Button:
            text: root.prop1.atr2
            on_press: root.modify2()
        Button:
            text: root.prop2
            on_press: root.modify3()
```

Button 1 and 2 change classe's varaibles but text on these buttons is not updated. Button 3 works as it should.

Any help would be aprreciated, I really want to avoid making every varaible from class a separate property.

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what do you want ? It seems binding those properties to a custom callback may help.

Comment: @ApuCoder I have quite complex struct-like class and I want to display it's attributes in Kivy and have buttons/ text inputs etc. that allow me to change these params. 

I also don't think that writing custom callback would help. When i change class's param (self.prop1.atr = something)  it seems like collback isn't called at all, becasue this atr isn't updated on gui. And from what I understand from reading docs, callback is there to update this value on GUI. Unless you ment something by callback or I misuderstood documentation

Comment: As per my understanding, whenever you're doing something like **self.prop1.atr = something**, it doesn't change the property `prop1` (in this case, *SomeStruct* object) but one of its attribute (*atr*). That being said, the object remains same, that's why `EventDispatcher` doesn't register its change (as nothing has changed). (Notice that `prop2` itself has changed completely, thus has been registered) But perhaps you can change them separately (which is too rigorous, I can understand) by binding them with a callback.